# Launching activity from another class,gives context error

Tags: c#, android, android-intent, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a RecyclerView with some content and when the user clicks on an item it should open a new activity with the information regarding the item.I am having the activity launch inside the custom adapter which i think is the problem but i can't figure another way to do it.
Here is my code:

MatchListCustomAdapter.cs

```
 private void MMainView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int position = mRecyclerView.GetChildLayoutPosition((View)sender);
            int indexPosition = (mgame.Count - 1) - position;
            mainAct.launchActivity(mgame[indexPosition].Id);
        }
```

and MainActivity.cs

```
public void launchActivity(long matchId)
        {
            Intent activity2 = new Intent(this, typeof(tabbedactivity));
            activity2.PutExtra("Match ID", matchId);
            StartActivity(activity2);


        }
```

It gives me this error `Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference`

Comment: It should be startActivity () not StartActivity () and try context.startActivity (intent)

Comment: @Alex Tselikas - you have deleted your package name on the top of activity

Comment: @AvinashSaran this is not the whole code of MainActivity.cs.It's just the function used for starting the activity.

Comment: @AlexTselikas Please check if package name is written there

Comment: @AlexTselikas Instead of typeof(tabbedactivity) write youractivityname.class

Comment: This is for java.In c# you use typeof(tabbedactivity)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding `Context context = Application.Context;` on my function.

Comment: And what did you do with 'context' then? I'm guessing you did something like this: Intent activity2 = new Intent(context, typeof(cMaterial));
                StartActivity(activity2);  
.
I have your exact same case and tried that but getting this error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference